# Compiling of Azerothcore fails in Visual Studio with errors related to OpenSSLCrypto and threadsSetup

Tags: c++, azerothcore

I am trying to do the classic setup and have been successful up until the installation/compilation of the core in visual studio. I have 1 build failing at the end with the following errors:

========= Build: 23 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped =========

[image]

I'm not familiar with all of these at all and I'm as specific as I can be. Apologies in advance if I'm not being clear or missing any details.

Edit: Okay I've found out what the problem was. I had the wrong verson of OpenSLL installed. It's working now. Thank you all.

Comment: 1. You might have just forgot to include the header. 2. There might be a preprocessor directive that removes the necessary headers. Nevertheless, better provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Please describe precisely what have you done to hit this error so that others may try and reproduce your problem/bug. What is your OS, compiler version, library versions, etc.

Comment: what version of OpenSSL have you instealled?

Comment: @FrancescoBorzi Thank you! Went to check and I had OpenSSL 3.0 installed, when the guide specificaly says 3.0 isn't supported. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the version of OpenSSL:

> OpenSLL **≥ 1.0.x** (OpenSSQL 3.0 is **NOT** supported)